# Can I configure log4cxx both using a property file and runtime configuration?

Tags: c++, logging, log4j, log4cxx

I would like to read in a configuration file to log4cxx, but during runtime, I would like to modify the appenders/loggers.  Can I do this?

Example log4cxx file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=all, console, file

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
log4j.appender.console.threshold=info

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %c [%p] %l %m%n
log4j.appender.file.filename=logfile.txt
log4j.appender.file.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

Example source:

```
PropertyConfigurator::configure("./LoggingConfig.txt");

auto rootlogger = Logger::getRootLogger();
DailyRollingFileAppenderPtr fileappender = rootlogger->getAppender(LOG4CXX_STR("file"));

fileappender->setFile(LOG4CXX_STR("thisisthenewfile.txt"));
```

--I've noticed that the output still writes to the original location in my configuration file.

Is it not possibly to configure using code (runtime) as well as a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to modify appender or logger through your code although you have log4crc file. I have done this in log4c in the following way.
`log4c_appender_t *myappender = log4c_appender_get("man.appender");`
to change prefix or log dir you need to create object of rolling file udata in the following way:
`rollingfile_udata_t *rfu = rollingfile_make_udata();`
then set path
`rollingfile_udata_set_logdir(rfu,"my/sample/path");`
or set prefix too
`rollingfile_udata_set_files_prefix(rfu,"myPrefix");`
then set rolling file with appender
`log4c_appender_set_udata(myappender,rfu);`
and also you may want to set the appender with category
`log4c_category_set_appender(mycat,myappender);`

Comment: I get segmentation fault on ' rollingfile_udata_set_logdir(rfu,"my/sample/path");'